# How to fetch phone contact to create group in windows phone8 app

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am developing a windows phone 8 application. i have to create a group of contacts using the phone contacts and make it available to access throughout the application.

Comment: I found out this link for such matter : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286414%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Research this Chooseers and Launchers of Windows Phone:

[How to use the save contact task for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394013%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

And you have also

- How to use the email compose task for Windows Phone
- How to use the save phone number task for Windows Phone
- How to use the phone number chooser task for Windows Phone

---

To create this group I think you can [Serialize and deserialize objects to disk (XAML / C #)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/esmsdn/p/windows8tipsandtricks-serializarydeserializarobjetosadisco-xamlcsharp.aspx)

Hope it's help

Answer (score 0):

First of all use the contacts class to fetch the contacts and do a blank search

```
 Contacts cons = new Contacts();

cons.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(Contacts_SearchCompleted);

cons.SearchAsync("", contactFilterKind, "Contacts Test #1");
```

Then when the search is over

```
void Contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
```

{
var allContacts = e.Result;
}

Here e.Result returns you the list of contact 
no ---- Next step you have two options

Either save a new contact with same info :- [saving contact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394013%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

or use local storage to save data ... Maybe in a text file .... and it will be available throughout the application .... If it is used for current purpose you can pass it to app resources (session) and use it over and over without calling the local storage

Application.current.resources .. Will act as a session and will be available through out the app....

There are still few more options like using db and all to access data .. but if memory is not an issue the app resources suits the best and if contacts is just not so so huge numbered :) please let me know if I can clarify further